# create boxplot from matrix with ggplot2

Tags: r, matrix, ggplot2, boxplot

I have been looking for this subject but I couldn't find a clear answer to my problem. 
I have a matrix like this:

```
    > myMatrix
           [,1]      [,2]         [,3]
 [1,] 1.0000000 0.8236821 5.174437e-01
 [2,] 0.2696589 0.1854324 1.000000e+00
 [3,] 0.3266629 0.1982345 1.000000e+00
 [4,] 1.0000000 0.7766927 1.807857e-01
 [5,] 1.0000000 0.5033586 3.662552e-01
 [6,] 1.0000000 0.9419056 4.989487e-02
 [7,] 1.0000000 0.6215466 9.446507e-01
 [8,] 1.0000000 0.9483751 8.328207e-01
 [9,] 1.0000000 0.4597556 1.756653e-01
[10,] 1.0000000 0.4842302 8.154578e-01
[11,] 1.0000000 0.5108767 1.912999e-01
[12,] 1.0000000 0.4315146 2.921003e-01
[13,] 1.0000000 0.8404401 8.960460e-03
[14,] 0.8190788 1.0000000 3.551697e-08
[15,] 1.0000000 0.5707248 1.897027e-03
[16,] 0.7768339 1.0000000 6.486805e-07
[17,] 0.7258489 1.0000000 3.463566e-06
[18,] 0.1839966 0.1848062 1.000000e+00
[19,] 0.3061347 0.1304444 1.000000e+00
[20,] 1.0000000 0.4425222 9.216534e-02
```

I would like to produce a boxplot using `ggplot2` which display this (3 groups which are the 3 columns):

```
boxplot(myMatrix)
```

I can't find the way with `ggplot2` to produce the same boxplot with my 3 groups.
Please, can someone help me?

Answer (score 5):

You have to transform your matrix into a data frame in the long format to use `ggplot2`:

```
dat <- stack(as.data.frame(myMatrix))
```

Now you can use `ggplot2`:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(x = ind, y = values))
```

[image]